# pthread_join() and sleep in main

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a program that creates two worker threads like the following:

```
void *Producer(void *threadarg){
    while (!terminate_producer){ //do something}
    printf("Producer: finalizing thread\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Consumer(void *threadarg){
    while (!terminate_consumer){ //do something}
    printf("Consumer: finalizing thread\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Initialize array of the worker threads
void initFuncArray(long result[])
{
    result[0] = (long)&Producer;
    result[1] = (long)&Consumer;
}

// The main method
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    long th_funcs[CPUS_NUM];
    initFuncArray(th_funcs);
    // threads data
    pthread_t tid[CPUS_NUM];
    thread_data prod_th_data[CPUS_NUM];
    bool pt = false;
    for (int i=0;i<CPUS_NUM;i++){
        prod_th_data[i].thread_id = i;
        pt = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *)th_funcs[i], (void*)&prod_th_data[i]);
        if (pt) return -1;
    }
    sleep(5);
    terminate_producer = true;
    pthread_join (tid[0], NULL);
    **sleep(1);**
    terminate_consumer = true;
    pthread_join (tid[1], NULL);

    // Exiting the main thread
    return 0;
}
```

My question is about a call to sleep before terminating the consumer thread. If I do not have this call, the program terminates normally. However, if I have that sleep, the program never terminates. I see the message that the producer thread terminates, but I do not get the message from the consumer thread. What might be the problem?

Following suggestions I modified the code as follows, however, the problem now appears even without a call to sleep in-between:

```
typedef void (*func_type) (void *);
pthread_mutex_t terminate_producer;
pthread_mutex_t terminate_consumer;

void *Producer(void *threadarg){
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&terminate_producer)){ //do something}
    printf("Producer: finalizing thread\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&terminate_producer);
    return NULL;
}

void *Consumer(void *threadarg){
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&terminate_consumer))
    printf("Consumer: finalizing thread\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&terminate_consumer);
    return NULL;
}

// Initialize array of the worker threads
void initFuncArray(func_type result[])
{
    result[0] = Producer;
    result[1] = Consumer;
}

// The main method
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    func_type th_funcs[CPUS_NUM];
    initFuncArray(th_funcs);
    // threads data
    pthread_t tid[CPUS_NUM];
    thread_data prod_th_data[CPUS_NUM];

    // Using mutexes as termination condition
    pthread_mutex_init(&terminate_producer,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&terminate_consumer,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&terminate_producer);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&terminate_consumer);

    bool pt = false;
    for (int i=0;i<CPUS_NUM;i++){
        prod_th_data[i].thread_id = i;
        pt = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, (void *)th_funcs[i], (void*)&prod_th_data[i]);
        if (pt) return -1;
    }
    sleep(5);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&terminate_producer);
    pthread_join (tid[0], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&terminate_consumer);
    pthread_join (tid[1], NULL);

    // Exiting the main thread
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `terminate_producer` atomic type? If not, than you have a data race.

Comment: Not the cause of your issue, but you declare two flags, `terminate_producer` and `terminate_consumer`, yet both threads only use `terminate_producer`.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the mistakes appeared due to copy/pasting ...

Comment: @zch: what do you mean by atomic type? Since both threads do not change the value of termination variables, how data race can occur?

Comment: @NeoSer, data race occurs when one thread writes and another writes or reads. In your case `main` writes and others read.

Comment: I think, it would be a problem if simultaneous write operations occurred. If one reads and the other one writes, the worst case is irrelevant data read by the former. However, it should terminate in the next iteration in any case ...

Comment: @NeoSer, in fact, in your example, if the optimizer could prove that `// do something` doesn't change `terminate_producer` it can replace your `while(!terminate_producer){}` to `if(!terminate_producer)while(1){}`

Comment: These are not logically equivalent statements ...

Comment: Why are you storing function pointers in a long? And pthread_create returns an int, not a bool.

Comment: What is a better way to do that?

Comment: Store them in a function pointer.

Comment: bool is essentially int  where 0 is false and everything else is true ... So, the returned result is implicitly cast.

Comment: @NeoSer, I can't find it in POSIX, but in common threading models data race is undefined behavior (anything can theoretically happen). And data race is defined as two unsynchronized accesses of which at least one is write. You need to use locks or atomics to get predictable results.

Comment: `bool` is not guaranteed to be an `int`. Conversion (there's no such thing as an "implicit cast" by definition) from an `int` will indeed occur in the way you guess, here, but you're needlessly losing information and it's a very unconventional and needlessly odd way of doing things. If you ever want to check what the return value was, for instance, you're going to have to change all your code.

Comment: Just a note. If I use return instead of pthread_exit in the threads, I get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

Flag `terminate_producer` represents a critical section. Producers are reading its value and main thread is rewriting it at the same time. Access to this flag should be protected with some synchronization mechanism such as mutex:

```
inline stopProducers() {
    /* GET LOCK */
    terminate_producer = 1;
    /* RELEASE LOCK */
}

inline unsigned char shouldProduce() {
    unsigned char terminate = 0;
    /* GET LOCK */
    terminate = terminate_producer;
    /* RELEASE LOCK */
    return !terminate;
}

void *Producer(void *threadarg){
    while (shouldProduce()){ /* do something */ }
    printf("Producer: finalizing thread\n");
    return NULL;  // <-- use return instead of pthread_exit
}
```

and in `main` you would call `stopProducers();` instead of rewriting the flag;

Comment: I think, it would be a problem if the main and the thread tried to write a value to terminate_producer at the same time. However, one is writing while the other one is reading. Thus, in the worst case the thread reads irrelevant data but terminates on the next iteration. The main will wait for the producer to finish before terminating the consumer in any case because of pthread_join ...

Comment: In case of using, e.g., mutexes, I do not need 'terminate' variable at all. I can simply check if a mutex is available and if so, terminate the thread (as in the code above).

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to the compiler heuristically concluding (as an optimization) that terminate_consumer is a variable which is only read in the consumer thread, so it "caches" it in a register and never reads it.

Can you change the declarations of terminate_producer and terminate_consumer to:

```
volatile int terminate_producer;
volatile int terminate_consumer;
```

.. and try again?

Comment: It's a tricky one. Is there something in the consumer loop which resets the terminate_consumer variable, or prevents it from ever being read?

Comment: No. The producer and the consumer threads just check the value on the respective termination variables in the loop condition and the termination variables do not appear in their bodies.

Comment: Your last modifications (with mutexes for terminate_xxx) are definitely wrong. You are now blocking on a locked mutex in each of those threads, not doing any work at all. Your original idea, with int's for terminate_xxx was valid, and it is *very* suspicious that it doesn't work - this is why I think there's something wrong somewhere else and not in those variables by themselves. Could you simply paste your exact code (with int's for terminate_xxx) on pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) or some similar service?